# ffmpeg is not working in web hosting server

Tags: php, ffmpeg

This is my code running in my local system, which works fine.

```
<?php 
    $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
    //$ffmpeg = "/home1/doitteco/public_html/bishal/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
    echo $ffmpeg."<br>";
    $videoFile = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Wildlife.wmv";
    $audioFile = "convert2Mp3.mp3";
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile $audioFile";
    echo $cmd."<br>";
    if (!shell_exec($cmd)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }

?>
```

And the following code is for the server:

```
<?php 
    //$ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
    $ffmpeg = "/home1/doitteco/public_html/bishal/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
    echo $ffmpeg."<br>";
    $videoFile = "/home1/doitteco/public_html/bishal/small.mp4";
    $audioFile = "convertMp3.mp3";
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile $audioFile";
    echo $cmd;
    if (!shell_exec($cmd)) {
        echo "<br>"."success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }

?>
```

I am not getting any error but the code is not working.It is not extracting the audio from the video file.

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file show what the issue us? That is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_. You _cannot_ program in php without monitoring that file...

Comment: Most likely this is a permission issue, by the way...

Comment: Does the `ffmpeg` command work if you run it manually in a command-line interface, or is the issue with your code?

Comment: Yes its in the command prompt in my local system but cannot track in the server,  and there is no error in the log file.

Comment: Did I need to install the ffmpeg in the server？ If yes, then please tell me how to install in the shared server.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your PHP configration settings from your C panel sometimes it may happen due to the `exec_shell` commands are disabled by your hosting server for security reasons.If you still are unable to do that please try change the URL of the image file use a relative path and surround it with quotes. For example:

```
$ffmpeg="path/to/your/ffmpeg.exe"; 
$video="path/to/video.mp4";
$audio="path/to/audio.mp3";
$cmd="$ffmpeg -i \"$video\" \"$audio\"";
```

if u are still unable to use ffmpeg then it may be because your hosting company do not allow that for the type of hosting you might have taken ,for that you need to upgrade your hosting type from shared hosting to VPS or dedicated hosting